Simple use of Schwarz lemma
Let $f: \mathbb{D}_1(0)\to \mathbb{H}$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane such that $f(0)=i$ Prove the following
$$\dfrac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}\leq |f(z)|\leq \dfrac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$
and $|f \prime(0)|\leq 2$.
What I did is I basically post compose the function $f$ with the Caley map and apply Schwarz lemma and got
$$\bigg|\dfrac{i-f(z)}{i+f(z)}\bigg|\leq |z|$$
on the disc. And for the second part I simply computed its derivative and plug in 0 and got the inequality for $|f \prime(0)|\leq 2$. But I have been playing around with inequality for hours and just can not get the first part. Could someone help me out? The best I could get is $\dfrac{1+|f(z)|}{|i-f(z)|}\geq \dfrac{1}{|z|}$ and hence $|f(z)|\geq \dfrac{|i-f(z)|-|z|}{|z|+1}$ and I can not argue $|i-f(z)|>1$ and nothing I could argue to show the other half of the inequality.
And also it doesnt seem to be true because Im$(i-f(z))\leq 1$.

I think your idea of applying the $C$-transform is fine. You can estimate
$$
\tfrac{1-\lvert f(z)\rvert}{1+\lvert f(z) \rvert} \leq \left \lvert \tfrac{i-f(z)}{i+f(z)} \right \rvert \leq \lvert z \rvert.
$$
Rearrange to obtain $\tfrac{1 - \lvert z \rvert}{1 + \lvert z \rvert}\leq \lvert f(z) \rvert$.
To get the other inequality estimate
$$
\tfrac{\lvert f(z)\rvert-1}{1+\lvert f(z) \rvert} \leq \left \lvert \tfrac{i-f(z)}{i+f(z)} \right \rvert \leq \lvert z \rvert
$$
and rearrange to find $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq \tfrac{1+\lvert z \rvert}{1-\lvert z \rvert}$.

Thanks, but how did you argue $\bigg|\dfrac{i-f(z)}{i+f(z)}\bigg|\geq \dfrac{1-|f(z)|}{1+|f(z)|}$?  I thought about using reverse triangle inequality but doesnt that only give you $|i-f(z)|\geq \big| 1-|f(z)|\big|$? What would be the argument that got rid of he absolute value on $1-|f(z)|$? Thanks

It is trivial that $\lvert 1 - \lvert f(z) \rvert \rvert \geq 1 - \lvert f(z) \rvert$ as every real number is smaller than its absolute value.
